# Java "Illegal key size" despite having installed JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes

I'm trying to use 256-bit AES encryption, but I am getting the following exception:
`java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size`

If I use a 128-bit key, then everything works just fine.

I've installed the JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files by replacing the two `.jar` files at `$JAVA_HOME$\jre\lib\security`. I've tried different versions of these files. I've re-installed a newer version of Java 8 and updated the PATH environment variable. Nothing works. I still get the error, and `Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength("AES/CBC/NoPadding")` still returns 128.

Comment: Fixed the problem. I can accept my answer in 2 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm on Windows 8. Originally I had Java 1.8.0_25 installed and there was only a single folder under `C:\Program Files\Java` which was `jdk1.8.0_25`. I was replacing the jar files at `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\jre\lib\security`. That didn't work.

After I installed the latest version (1.8.0_111), apart from the new jdk folder `jdk1.8.0_111` a new folder appeared: `jre1.8.0_111`.

Replacing the two jar files in `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\lib\security` fixed the problem. I also replaced the ones under `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\security` - I am not sure whether that was necessary or not, but it works.